# Query based shifting elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

We are given two numbers n and m. n indicates the number of elements in the array and m indicates number of queries.We are given m queries.We need to perform two types of queries on the array.Queries can be of two types, type 1 and type 2.

TYPE 1 queries are represented as (1 i j ) : Modify the given array by removing elements between i to j position and adding them to the front.

TYPE 2 queries are represented as (2 i j ) : Modify the given array by removing elements between i to j position and adding them to the back.

Our task is to simply print the difference array[1]-array[n] after the execution of queries followed by printing the array.

INPUT FORMAT:
First line consists of two space-separated integers, n and m. 
Second line contains n integers, which represent the elements of the array. 
m queries follow. Each line contains a query of either type 1 or type 2 in the form (type i j).

OUTPUT FORMAT:
Print the absolute value a[0]-a[n] in the first line. 
Print elements of the resulting array in the second line. Each element should be separated by a single space.

EXAMPLE:
Given array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].
After execution of query(1 2 4),the array becomes(2,3,4,1,5,6,7,8).
After execution of query(2 3 5),the array becomes(2,3,6,7,8,4,1,5).
After execution of query(1 4 7),the array becomes(7,8,4,1,2,3,6,5).
After execution of query(2 1 4),the array becomes(2,3,6,5,7,8,4,1).

For the problem,I wrote a program as follows:

```
int main() 
{
int n,m;
cin>>n;
cin>>m;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}

int count; // counter to control no of queries to accept
for(count=0;count<m;count++)
{
   int type,start,end; // 3 parts of query 
   cin>>type;cin>>start;cin>>end;

   if(type==1)
   { 
     //calculated difference between (start,end) to find no of iterations

     for(int i=0;i<=(start-end);i++)
     { // t is temporary variable
       int t=arr[(start-1)+i]; //(start-1) as index starts from 0
       arr[(start-1)+i]=arr[i];
       arr[i]=t;
     }
   }
   else
   {
      for(int i=0;i<=(start-end);i++)
     {
       int t=arr[(start-1)+i];
   // elements inserted from end so we subtract (n)-(start-end)
       arr[(start-1)+i]=arr[(n-1)-(start-end)+i];
       arr[(n-1)-(start-end)+i]=t;
     }
   }
   count++;
   //increment count
}

int absolute=abs(arr[0]-arr[n-1]);
cout<<absolute<<"\n";

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the code to work correctly,but surprisngly did not even display the output correctly as well.Here is the test case:
INPUT:
8 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 4
2 3 5
1 4 7
2 1 4

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
1
2 3 6 5 7 8 4 1

MY OUTPUT:
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

I had dry run the code many times but cannot seem to understand where the problem is coming from.Please look at the code and provide me suggestions.

Comment: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) will help.

Comment: Can you please tell me with modifications in my code? Thanks for the pains.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop condition is wrong.

---

CORRECT WAY : for ( int i = 0; i<=(end - start ) ; i++)

Comment: I corrected the code but it still does not work.The answer is wrong by 2 numbers and the output format is displaying with new line,which I cannot understand.